# How do you rip two or more specific titles with makemkvcon?

Tags: dvd, matroska

I've been starting to use the CLI to MakeMKV (makemkvcon) and I'm wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to rip more than one specific title from a DVD at a time without rescanning. Say I want to rip titles 0, 2 and 7 then I would expect a command something like this would be available

```
makemkvcon64 mkv disc:0 0,2,7 "\path\to\output\dir"
```

Otherwise, if you just loop over each title separately then makemkvcon does a full disc rescan which is a big waste of time.

The usage.txt file from the MakeMKV site shows how to rip a single title, and there is also an option to rip all titles but nothing about two or more specific titles. [This](http://www.makemkv.com/forum2/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=8413) (unanswered) forum post makes the good point, I think, that the GUI is capable of ripping specific titles without having to do a rescan.

I've done a decent amount of Googling, but feel free to show me up with your better Google-fu, and all I found that was related was that forum post and [this](https://github.com/JasonMillward/Autorippr) Git repo that uses MakeMKV to automate ripping. As promising as that repo sounds, from what I saw in the source it simply runs a for loop over the list of titles you want.

I don't have access to a linux machine (I'm running on Windows) but I was thinking that using this idea (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12509) could be a way to see how the GUI interfaces with the actual binary that does the ripping to extract the multi-title input.

A bunch of random ideas I've tried for separating the titles in the makemkvcon command

```
0,1,7
"0,1,7"
0;1;7
"0;1;7"
0:1:7
"0:1:7"
0 1 7
"0 1 7"
0-1-7
"0-1-7"
0_1_7
"0_1_7"
"0|1|7"
title:0 title:1 title:7
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the exact same question for a while. I eventually gave up and wrote a bash script that uses makemkvcon to read the disc once, writes that data to a file, then parses that file based on my various preferences and loops through and rips the titles I want.

It's exactly as you describe it. The overhead of reading the disc occurs for each title ripped. In the GUI, it definitely processes multiple titles in one swipe.

I've looked at the link you posted and will try the process they detail to try to get a better look at what the makemkv GUI is doing to trigger a single read and maybe, hopefully, we can duplicate the process in makemkvcon.

Answer (score 0):

The best I have found is using the `all` keyword combined with the `--minlength=<seconds>` parameter. This tells it to rip all titles that match the minimum length requirement to the destination folder. It's not perfect, but it could be better than looping through titles one by one. Example:

```
makemkvcon64 --minlength=600 mkv disc:0 all E:\media\mkv
```